# Storing a CALayer/CGLayer on disk with iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I have a `CGLayerRef` with content on it. How can I store this so that the app can quickly retrieve it and display it again? I tried converting it to a PNG and storing using Core Data but it's pretty slow to display, so I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: Depends on how big the image is. Remember that because an image is small on disk doesn't mean that it is small on memory or when loading. image size (in memory) will be width*height*4 (pixels of width and height multiplied by the bit depth of each pixel) that may give some insight into the loading speed of your file. There is not really a good way that would be much faster other than to buffer, just make sure to watch memory usage and test on the device.

Comment: You said CGLayerRef, but it seems like you may really mean CALayer. Is that right?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to persist it between launches, not just while the app is loaded?